# Using this.props or this.state directly vs setting const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, react-props, react-state

I'm new to react and as I'm looking at examples, I see that a lot of tutorials don't use `this.props` or `this.state` directly. Instead, they will set a const at the beginning of the function. I've used the two interchangeably without seeing any difference in functionality.

Are there any gains to using `const`?

ie.

```
const {
    error
} = this.state;

{error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
```

vs

```
{this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error.message}</p>}
```

Comment: There's no functional difference, it's a matter of preference (and therefore off topic here as opinion based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `Destructuring`, a feature of ES6.

There are no differences in functionality but there are little benefits of using destructuring.

First, cleaner code. If you destructure an object at the top of your code block, it appears more clear to the reader what variables you are going to use.

Second, it puts object properties in local variables which can improve performance, especially if you are using the variables multiple times like in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you have yourself stated that there is no difference at all and it is true. My simple answer of using const is

After u define this way

```
const {error} = this.state;
```

now u can just use term (error) in the following codes instead of lengthy (this.state.error)
So it is just for simplicity